# Set or replace textContent in Facebook's chat

Tags: javascript, facebook, google-chrome-extension, reactjs

I'm developing a Chrome extension, which allows the user to replace the text of their Facebook chat message before they send it.

**For example**, if the user types *"Hello there"*, I want to allow them to replace the chat input field with *"There hello"*, and leave it up to the user to send the altered message.

[image]

**The problem** is that I am able to change the text by editing the `textContent` attribute of the input, but the chat widget doesn't know of the change, probably because the right events have not fired, so when I press Enter to send the altered message nothing happens. Additionally, I am not able to delete the changed text with the mouse nor the keyboard.

I've tried simulating keyboard input, but with no success. I'm open to accepting a working solution that involves that.

**My question** is, how to I replace the text in the chat input field so that the chat widget detects and accepts it?

**Note:** I am not using jQuery, so I would prefer solutions that do not use it.

Comment: I don't know if/how you might hook into it, but Facebook is using React, which is capturing the events and the HTML you see is the output.

Comment: I spent *waaay* too long trying to figure this out. It's not impossible, but 1) it's very hard and 2) If Facebook changes their code, your widget will break and 3) If Facebook ever turns off the devtools hook in production, you have no hope . You basically want to use the `window.__REACT_DEVTOOLS_GLOBAL_HOOK__.reactDevtoolsAgent` object, the react component instance is somewhere in there but it's very hard to find. I can find the DOM element but not the instance itself. Once you get the instance you can trigger the onKeyPress event or something. It's likely an insurmountable problem.

Comment: @miniml I don't have facebook so would struggle to look at this for you... is there some kind of sandbox or JSFiddle-esque environment that I could test in?

Comment: @PeterScott, unfortunately (and that's what makes this so hard) the only way to test this is using a real Facebook account :/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After spending too much time on this I finally figured out that sending a `textInput` event to the editable element can change its text, and will trigger all React.js events.

```
var setText = function(el, text) { 
    var te = document.createEvent('TextEvent'); 
    te.initTextEvent('textInput', true, true, window, text);
    el.dispatchEvent(te); 
}
```

I had tried something similar before, but I was sending the `input` event, which apparently does not work in WebKit and Chrome.

Thanks to all who participated and tried to help!

Answer (score 1):

The initTextEvent is deprecated, now should use:

```
    const inputEvent = new InputEvent('input', {
      bubbles: true,
      cancelable: true,
      composed: true,
      inputType: 'insertText',
      data: 'your_data'
    });
  
    el.dispatchEvent(inputEvent);
```

Comment: Yay! only thing that worked for me after lots of googling!